# Why does this loop get progressively slower?

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance

```
for (i = 0; i < $('body > p font i').length; i++) {
    current = [$('body > p font i').eq(index), $('body > p font i').eq(index).index('body > p font u, body > p font i')];
    getState(current[1]);
}

function getState(index) {
    // Lookup the object's index, then crawl up until you find a match
    while ($('body > p font u, body > p font i').eq(--index).filter('u').length == 0);
    console.log($('body > p font u, body > p font i').eq(index).text());
}
```

Fairly simple question. I'm iterating a jQuery result set against a selector filter until I find a match, climbing up through the result set as I go.

The longer this loop runs, the slower it becomes, almost exponentially so.

Comment: Do you mean to have a semi-colon at the end of that first line?

Comment: Yes, I want to find the index of the matching result. Added the code beforehand for clarification.

Comment: use `i` instead of index. in 2nd line + why you are storing element in array if you only need 2nd element.

Comment: If no match found the while loop never ends

Comment: For starters, you should cache your jQuery objects. `var $elements = $('body > p font i'); $elements.eq(...`

Comment: @gaetanoM It finds a match. If it didn't, the page would freeze and not continue to loop again. It doesn't freeze, it simply runs very slow and gets slower.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are seraching in the DOM tree on each iteration which is an expensive operation, the solution is cache:

```
var nodes = $('body > p font i');
for (var i = 0, size = nodes.length; i < size; i++) {
    current = [nodes.eq(index),nodes.eq(index).index('body > p font u, body > p font i')];
}
```

Comment: Right, I get that bit. Why does it cause it to slow down over time as opposed to just be slow in the first place? 

Does it cache itself somewhere over and over?

Comment: @Thirk If you're moving *back* through the list then first time you only check one item, then two, then three, etc. etc.

Comment: @kidwon what if something add element into body ??

Comment: @MikeC mm, I should have realized that, I think that explains the slowdown. Thanks!

Comment: @Mahi what if metor hits the Earth, it will go wrong ofcource :)

Comment: @kidwon Fitting response given your avatar. Or was that on purpose?

Comment: @Thirk I was just joking with Mahi :)